# Quiero subir una imagen maniputar su tamaño con InterventionImage, guardar en el servidor y luego subir a Google drive, con Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-drive, storage

Quiero subir una imagen por medio de un formulario maniputar su tamaño con InterventionImage, guardar en el servidor y luego subir a Google drive, con laravel.

Muestro mi codigo.

```
$archivo = $request->file('archivo');
        
$name = 'test_' . time() . '.' . $archivo->guessExtension();
        
$url = storage_path('app\public\img/' . $name);

$img =  Image::make($archivo);
        
$img->resize(333, null, function ($constraint) {
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$img->save($url);
        
$contents = Storage::disk('public')->get('img/' . $name);

$file = Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("", $contents, $name);
```

Me da el siguiente error:

[image: fopen(): Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain any null bytes]

Comment: Hola tienes razon, me falto el error que me da, es el siguiente: fopen(): Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain any null bytes

Comment: No coloques "solucionado": cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Ten siempre presente que [es.so] es un sitio de _preguntas y respuestas_, no un foro.

Comment: Si coloque pero creo que no guardo, pero gracias

Comment: Es que no debés colocarlo... Por eso revirtieron tu edición. Leé de nuevo el comentario anterior :) Como te decía, debes [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta (¡lee el enlace!). Es el check que está a la izquierda de tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya conseguie la solucion:
Cree un objeto UploadedFile desde una ruta absoluta

```
public function pathToUploadedFile( $path, $test = true ) {
        $filesystem = new Filesystem;
        
        $name = $filesystem->name( $path );
        $extension = $filesystem->extension( $path );
        $originalName = $name . '.' . $extension;
        $mimeType = $filesystem->mimeType( $path );
        $error = null;
    
        return new UploadedFile( $path, $originalName, $mimeType, $error, $test );
}
```

Luego lo llamo desde mi metodo

```
$archivo = $request->file('archivo');
        
        $name = 'test_' . time() . '.' . $archivo->guessExtension();
        
        $url = storage_path('app\public\img/' . $name);

        $img =  Image::make($archivo);
        
        $img->resize(333, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        $img->save($url);
        
        $contents = Storage::disk('public')->get('img/' . $name);
        
        $test = $this->pathToUploadedFile($url, true);
        
        $file = Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("", $test, $name);
```